# Unable to fetch photos using facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the photos of a user from facebook using php api. Currently I don't have permissions to fetch the photos from facebook. But I am using the same id which has been used to create the facebook app. I heard that we can use the same id (the one used to create the app) for testing everything from facebook. My code for fetching user photos is :-

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{user-id}/photos'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Response of the above code  :-   Array()

It is returning a blank array. Is it because I do not have permissions to fetch photos or any other reason?

Comment: `I heard that we can use the same id... `  from where you heard ? can you link the source ?

Comment: Sorry about that i dont have link. Will facebook ever approve permissions to an app without a prototype ready. Last time when i tried they asked me links of the web application and where the app will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an app *admin/developer/tester* you can experiment with permissions without the need of submitting for app review. **However**, you still need to request the permission to be able to access the data of these endpoints.

You can easily test this on the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), where you could easily request permissions and query endpoints.